# Unicode Currency Symbols not rendering in BIRT pdf

Tags: pdf, unicode, birt

we need help with getting the Costa Rican Colon, South Korea Won, Philippine Peso, and Indian Rupee currency symbols to display when running a BIRT pdf report. Within our .rptDesign we have 5 Text Items (HTML Dynamic Text) that contains a Unicode to display currency symbols. Out of the 5 currency symbols none of them display except for the Israeli Shekel (₪).

[list of currency symbols and unicodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG9ZE.jpg)

We are running BIRT 3.7.2 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago). We have two rpm of fonts that are installed with tomcat rpm, msttcorefonts-2.5 and fonts-chinese-3.02.  The fonts have not been updated in long time, so we updated to the latest 2.6.1 version; https:// sourceforge. net/ projects/ mscorefonts2/ files/ and rpm 
https:// downloads. sourceforge. net/ project/ mscorefonts2/ rpms/ msttcore-fonts-installer-2.6-1.noarch.rpm

The font package that was installed (http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/ 2.5.1), BIRT font configuration

```
<font>
    <font-paths>
        <path path="/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts" />
        <path path="/usr/share/fonts/default/Type1" />
    </font-paths>
<!-- Not All Chinese Characters Displaying in report
     - Overriding the all-fonts BIRT report configuration to use Simplified Chinese (STSong-Light) font encoding catalog instead of Traditional Chinese (MSung-Light).
     - BIRT's default PDF font configuration is in plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.fonts\fontsConfig_pdf.xml
     - BIRT bug (Bug 427672)
-->
    <composite-font name="all-fonts">
        <font font-family="Times-Roman" catalog="Western" />
        <font font-family="STSong-Light" catalog="Chinese" />
        <font font-family="HeiseiKakuGo-W5" catalog="Japanese" />
        <font font-family="HYGoThic-Medium" catalog="Korean" />
    </composite-font>
</font>
```

The debugging we did like echo –e “<>” to confirm the character is available in OS, but not getting rendered in BIRT.

Would anyone know why none of the symbols display except for Israeli Shekel (₪) and how can we get the other currency symbols display when rendering the report in pdf? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display recent unicode symbols use maintained fonts that have been updated this millenium (and don't make choices based on last millenium FAQs).

msttcorefonts is an old gratisware dump of Microsoft's core fonts for the web, never updated since (released by Microsoft in the 1990's to help IE4 kill Netscape, and abandoned  as soon as Netscape stopped twitching,  yes, it's that old). It does not include all the fixes and extensions done since in the fonts as shipped in Windows. It uses very early "smart font" hinting metadata full of bogus values that need to be worked around by font renderers (when they bother). Nobody serious uses it except nostalgics of win95 pixelated text that do not care about internationalization.

fonts-something packages date from X11 time and have not been updated since (modern RHEL/Fedora packages uses the -fonts suffix naming convention for about a decade). You really think anyone releases modern fonts as Type1 nowadays?

Invest some time in installing RHEL/EPEL font packages to choose among the nice panel of available modern fonts, there is a lot of change every release, it's not the font desert of past decades anymore. Most Fedora font packages should work as-is in RHEL too.